# Fetch file from local file system or from external location using jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have a requirement where I need to fetch entries from the file I upload and add each entry to a table. To fetch file from local system, I can use file upload utility provided by JQuery, but for fetching file from the HTTP URL i don't know how to do it. It would be grateful if there is a mechanism to achieve both requirements.

Example: Get file from location "http://www.somesite.com/test.txt" and parse the content from this file and add each entry to a table.

Please let me know. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: *"To fetch file from local system, I can use file upload utility provided by JQuery..."* jQuery doesn't provide a file upload utility, you must be using a plugin.

Comment: Yeah Sorry. So do you know how to achieve this by fetching file from specified URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL is on the same origin as the page you're doing this on, you can use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

If it isn't and you don't control the other site, you probably can't do this from the browser, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In order to be able to do it, the site in question (e.g., `somesite.com`) would have to allow your origin to access its pages via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (and you'd have to be using a [modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) — and note that while IE8 and IE9 support CORS, they do it in a broken way that jQuery doesn't support, but there's a plugin that fixes that).

So you'd have to retrieve the information from a server, not from the client. That could be *your* server, but there are alternatives. One is to [use YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax), since [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) lets you query Yahoo's servers for information on other web pages.